# Error converting data type varchar to bigint in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bigint

I'm trying to call this procedure with the `usp_TimesheetsAuditsLoadAllbyId 42747, NULL` command.

But I always get an error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure usp_TimesheetsAuditsLoadAllById, Line 9
>   Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

The `ID` of `TimesheetsAudits` table is a `bigint` type. I tried several types of conversions and casts, but I'm really stuck right now.

Hope somebody can help. Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TimesheetsAuditsLoadAllById]
(
    @Id INT,
    @StartDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SELECT TOP 51 * 
   FROM 
      (SELECT TOP 51 
          ID,
          Type, 
          ReferrerId,
          CAST(Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Description,
          OnBehalfOf,
          Creator,
          DateCreated 
       FROM 
          TimesheetsAudits 
       WHERE 
          (ReferrerID = @Id) AND
          (@StartDate IS NULL OR DateCreated < @StartDate)
       ORDER BY
          DateCreated DESC

       UNION

       SELECT TOP 51 
          tia.ID,
          tia.Type, 
          tia.ReferrerId,
          '[Day: ' + CAST(DayNr AS VARCHAR(5)) + '] ' + CAST(tia.Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Description,
          tia.OnBehalfOf,
          tia.Creator,
          tia.DateCreated 
       FROM 
          TimesheetItemsAudits tia
       INNER JOIN 
          TimesheetItems ti ON tia.ReferrerId = ti.ID
       WHERE 
          (ti.TimesheetID = @Id) AND
          (@StartDate IS NULL OR tia.DateCreated < @StartDate)
       ORDER BY 
          tia.DateCreated DESC) t
   ORDER BY 
       t.DateCreated DESC
END
```

Table definition for tables from comments:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetsAudits]( 
  [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL, 
  [ReferrerId] [varchar](15) NOT NULL, 
  [Description] [text] NULL, 
  [OnBehalfOf] [varchar](10) NULL, 
  [Creator] [varchar](10) NOT NULL, 
  [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL
)



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetItemsAudits]( 
  [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL, 
  [ReferrerId] [varchar](15) NOT NULL, 
  [Description] [text] NULL, 
  [OnBehalfOf] [varchar](10) NULL, 
  [Creator] [varchar](10) NOT NULL, 
  [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Table Structure for TimesheetAudits?

Comment: What type is referrerId an description?

Comment: table description for TimesheetItemsAudits will help as well.  Do both tables have ID as bigint?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetsAudits](
     [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
     [ReferrerId] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
     [Description] [text] NULL,
     [OnBehalfOf] [varchar](10) NULL,
     [Creator] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
     [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetItemsAudits](
 [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 [ReferrerId] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
 [Description] [text] NULL,
 [OnBehalfOf] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [Creator] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,

Comment: Above are the structure of both tables

Comment: I added tour tables to the original question but they are identical. Please edit your original question accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You perform an INNER JOIN of [dbo].[TimesheetsAudits] and TimesheetItems ti ON tia.ReferrerId = ti.ID

tia.[ReferrerId] is varchar and  ti.[ID] is [bigint].

I'd expect a value in tia.[ReferrerId] that cannot be converted to bigint.

Try the following:

```
SELECT [ReferrerId] FROM TimesheetItemsAudits WHERE ISNUMERIC(ReferrerId) = 0
```

This may help you to find the "offending rows".

Comment: A word of caution for other googlers: Be careful with ISNUMERIC(), as as it will also validate to true on both scientific notation as well as some currency symbols. More on that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx. You may be able to use TRY_CAST() (introduced in SQL 2012) to vet your conversions in cases where you have to deal with these elements.